# Changing default value of DateTime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

In my SQL database all the the tables have a column with `postDate`. That column is assigned a default value using `getDate()`.
Recently our SQL Server changed location. So there is a date and time difference between this location and where the SQL Server is hosted. How can I change my default  option to `getDate() + (GMT+03:00)`?

Comment: this can be fixed using a sub query, but I'm afraid that you cannot assign a sub query to a default volumn value. You have 2 practical option from what I see: 1. explicitly inserting the `postDate` value. 2. using `SWITCHOFFSET(postDate , '+03:00')` when using the postDate column.

Comment: Just one more reason why you should use utc for this kind of thing...

Comment: I do not understand the actual question. Do you want to know how to replace an existing ("anonymous") default constraint? Or do you want to know how to define your new default constraint to include the +03 offset? (In the latter case, I would agree with Zohar Peled and - when possible - use UTC datetime values in your DB and let your client software handle the (local) date/time representation.) And can you please clearly specify which DBMS you are using? (I assume SQL Server, since you talk about getdate(), but it would be nice to know for sure.)